# Python27 - Convert tuple time to datetime object

Tags: python, datetime

I'm trying to get a timestamp from an email like this:

```
Received: by 10.64.149.4 with SMTP id tw4csp1211013ieb;
    Thu, 4 Aug 2016 07:02:01 -0700 (PDT)
```

First of all, I parse the timestamp with:

```
d = email.utils.parsedate('Thu, 4 Aug 2016 07:02:01 -0700 (PDT)')

Result: (2016, 8, 4, 7, 2, 1, 0, 1, -1)
```

Here comes the problem. I try to convert the result to a datetime, but in vain.

```
d = email.utils.parsedate('Thu, 4 Aug 2016 07:02:01 -0700 (PDT)')

date_object = datetime(d)

Result: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "data.py", line 12, in <module>
    date_object = datetime(d)
TypeError: an integer is required
```

What's the problem?

Comment: Read about `datetime.strptime`: https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime and https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior

Comment: @DeepSpaceI I can not use strptime, because the format %Z is a bad directive

Comment: Which means  what?

Comment: @DeepSpace If I try to use datetime.strptime(some_date) where some_date is like yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss Z, I get the error "%z is a bad directive" and the datetime object is not created. And as I said, I'm using Python 2.7

Comment: `strptime` works the same on Python 2 and 3.

Comment: `datetime.datetime` object class constructor get only 8 arguments, you are passing 9

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`email.utils.parsedate` [returns a 9 tuple similar to the structure `struct_time` but with the index 6,7 and 8 unusable](https://docs.python.org/2/library/email.util.html#email.utils.parsedate)

[`struct_time`:](https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.struct_time)

```
Index   Attribute   Values
0       tm_year     (for example, 1993)
1       tm_mon      range [1, 12]
2       tm_mday     range [1, 31]
3       tm_hour     range [0, 23]
4       tm_min      range [0, 59]
5       tm_sec      range [0, 61]; see (2) in strftime() description
6       tm_wday     range [0, 6], Monday is 0
7       tm_yday     range [1, 366]
8       tm_isdst    0, 1 or -1
```

And `datetime` objects require different values for its constructor

`datetime.datetime(year, month, day[, hour[, minute[, second[, microsecond[, tzinfo]]]]])`

You could directly create a `datetime` using the useful parts of your tuple as

`date_object = datetime(*d[0:6])`

---

Edit: Careful with this, because this will create the object in local time, disregarding the time zone information.

---

Edit 2: You can solve this by using `strptime`, you just need to cut the `(PDT)` from the end of your string, since PDT is not a valid name for `tzinfo`, but `-0700` is enough

Answer (score 1):

Check out [`calendar.timegm`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/calendar.html#calendar.timegm) or [`time.mktime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.mktime) for converting a struct_time tuple to a float. You can then use [`datetime.fromtimestamp`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp) with that float to create a DateTime object.

Answer (score 1):

Last two items of the tuple are strange, they don't look like timezone data. But if you don't need timezone aware `datetime` object, you can do something like this `datetime(*d[:-2])`